# returns 0 rows when converting old code to Tsql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, translate

I am translating a query from some other platform to T-SQL.

I was told as, I went along in SSMS what code was invalid, so I think I changed everything, and now the code runs with the output of 0 Rows affected. The old code finds rows.

Anything obviously wrong with this code?

```
SELECT 'invalid_character_in_prod_ID ', 
       a.client_id, 
       a.prod_id 
FROM   tsc.ems_tvc_prod a, 
       tsc.ems_tvc_clnt_bus c 
WHERE  a.client_id = c.client_id 
       AND a.bus_unit = c.bus_unit 
       AND ts_sub_org = 'FORD' 
       AND ( Patindex(prod_id, Char(9)) > 0 
              OR Patindex(prod_id, Char(160)) > 0 )
```

Comment: You need `charindex` not `patindex` anyway.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Don't use terms like `(unk)-SQL` as some kind of cryptic shorthand for "unknown SQL" - you fooled at least a handful of people into thinking you were really using a platform named like that...

Answer (score 5):

Your use of [`PATINDEX`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx) is incorrect.

Try:

```
AND ( Patindex('%'+Char(9)+'%', prod_id) > 0 
              OR Patindex('%'+Char(160)+'%', prod_id) > 0 )
```

...or just use [`CHARINDEX`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx) as @MartinSmith suggests.

Comment: UNk sql means I dont know what flavor of sql the older code was written in.  if it helps, i can go get the original code. Thanks

Comment: @JeffGreen your order of parameters for `PATINDEX` is backwards, though. Are you sure you're using `CHARINDEX` correctly?

Comment: old code -  select 'invalid_character_in_prod_ID ', a.client_id, a.prod_id
from ems_tvc_prod  a, ems_tvc_clnt_bus  c
where a.client_id = c.client_id
and a.bus_unit = c.bus_unit
and ts_sub_org = 'FORD' 
and (instr(prod_id,chr(9)) > 0
or instr(prod_id,chr(160)) > 0)

Comment: New code - select 'invalid_character_in_prod_ID ', a.client_id, a.prod_id
from tsc.ems_tvc_prod  a, tsc.ems_tvc_clnt_bus  c
where a.client_id = c.client_id
and a.bus_unit = c.bus_unit
and ts_sub_org = 'FORD' 
and (charindex(prod_id,char(9)) > 0
or charindex(prod_id,char(160)) > 0)

Comment: @JeffGreen again, your parameters **are backwards**...you're looking for the entire `prod_id` inside `Char(9)` which ain't gonna work.

Comment: Please refer to the links I put in my answer to the documentation for those functions.

Comment: @JeffGreen Perhaps you have a background in VB or similar, where the construct is `instr(bigger_string, smaller_pattern)` - in T-SQL it is the opposite, `charindex(smaller_pattern, bigger_string)`. The documentation JNK points out in his answer should show you that, too.